# Group together results based from one column or another

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table/model for messages which has the following columns `sendid` and `receiveid`.

If I send a message, the following will be entered into the database.

```
sendid = 1 (This is my user id)
receiveid = 12334
```

If I receive a message, the following will be entered into the database

```
sendid = 12334
receiveid = 1 (This is my user id)
```

I need a query that will get all of the messages and group them by the person (Basically an ID which is not me). So if I *send* a message to the user ID `23123` then they will appear at the top. If I then *receive* a message from user ID `8398` then they will now appear at the top instead. As you can see, the person can either be in the column `sendid` or `receiveid` so this is where the struggle kicks in.

This is the query I have at the moment. it does not load up messages that I have sent. So if I sent a message to user ID `2323` then they wont go to the top of the page. It is extremely inefficient (takes 1-2 seconds in production). It's a pretty awful query. Apologies as I'm not well versed in SQL.

```
$getMessages = \App\Message::with("sender")->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    return $query->select(DB::raw('max(id)'))
                ->from(with(new \App\Message)->getTable())
                ->where('receiveid', \Auth::user()->id)
                ->groupBy('sendid');
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate(10, ['*'], 'messages_page');
```

What can be done to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, it can be solved like this:

```
//subquery to retrieve all recievers' ids
$recieversSubquery = \App\Message::where('sendid', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('receiveid as pen_pal_id', 'created_at');

//subquery to retrieve all senders' ids
$sendersSubquery = \App\Message::where('receiveid', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->select('sendid as pen_pal_id', 'created_at');

//final query with ordering and pagination
$getMessages = $recieversSubquery
    ->union($sendersSubquery)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->simplePaginate(10, ['*'], 'messages_page');
```

Here is yet another solution:

```
$getMessages = \App\Message::select('created_at', DB::raw('CASE WHEN sendid = ? THEN receiveid ELSE sendid END as pen_pal_id', [\Auth::user()->id]))
    ->where('sendid', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->orWhere('receiveid', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->simplePaginate(10, ['*'], 'messages_page');
```